# Javascript - Function Not Changing Global Variable

Tags: javascript

My Code (Javascript):

```
var num = 0;
function change(){
    var num = 10;
}
        change();
        document.write(num);
```

The result should be **10** but it is showing 0. Why?
If the code is wrong, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're declaring a new variable num in the scope of change. Remove the var keyword

Comment: @Axnyff Got it, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting another local variable called `num`.

Just change the inner `var num` to `num`.